# Creating a horizontal scrolling table in shopify

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I am trying to create a website using Shopify. I tried to edit the code and add three tabs in the product page. 1 Tab will be the description the other is Size chart and the other is reviews. I was able to put the description and reviews in the tab but when I put the size chart and look the website from the phone the size chart doesnt fit. So I wanted to create e horizonal scroll for the table.
Below is the html, CSS and Java code that I put in the product-template.liquid, theme.css, theme.java respectively. Below you can see a picture of the tabs:
[Website picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPMuI.png)

I used this code to create the review tabs.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    .tab-content
    {
        display:none;
    }
    .tab-content.active
    {
        display:block;
    }
    ul.tabs
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding:0;
        margin-left:0;
    }
    li.tab
    {
        display:inline-block;
        padding:10px 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    li.tab.active
    {
        color:grey;
        border-bottom:1px solid red;
    }
 
    </style>
 
</head>
<body>
 
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab" data-content-id="Description">tab 1</li>
        <li class="tab" data-content-id="Size chart">tab 2</li>
        <li class="tab" data-content-id="Reviews">tab 3</li>
    </ul>
 
    <div id="tab-content-1" class="tab-content">content 1</div>
    <div id="tab-content-2" class="tab-content">{{product.metafields.meta.sizechart}}</div>
    <div id="tab-content-3" class="tab-content">content 3</div>
 
    <script>
        tabs= document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
        tabContents= document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content');
 
        tabs.forEach(function(tab){
            tab.addEventListener('click',function(){
 
                contentId = this.dataset.contentId;
                content = document.getElementById(contentId);
 
                tabContents.forEach(function(content){
                    content.classList.remove('active');
                });
 
                tabs.forEach(function(tab){
                    tab.classList.remove('active');
                });
 
                this.classList.add('active');
                content.classList.add('active');
            });
        });
    </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I tried a lot of things to make the horizontal scroll bar. But it still now working. If anyone has any experience with shopify can you please help me.

The table in html:

```
<div style='overflow-x:auto'>
<table class="t2">
<thead>
<tr>
<td style="width: 54px;" rowspan="2">Size</td>
<td style="width: 112px;" colspan="2">Length</td>
<td style="width: 96px;" colspan="2">Waist</td>
<td style="width: 86.6px;" colspan="2">Hip</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 57px;">CM</td>
<td style="width: 55px;">INCH</td>
<td style="width: 39px;">CM</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">INCH</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">CM</td>
<td style="width: 46.6px;">INCH</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 54px;">S</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">100</td>
<td style="width: 55px;">39.37 </td>
<td style="width: 39px;">61</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">24.02 </td>
<td style="width: 40px;">95</td>
<td style="width: 46.6px;">37.40 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 54px;">M</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">101.5</td>
<td style="width: 55px;">39.96 </td>
<td style="width: 39px;">65</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">25.59 </td>
<td style="width: 40px;">99</td>
<td style="width: 46.6px;">38.98 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 54px;">L</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">103</td>
<td style="width: 55px;">40.55 </td>
<td style="width: 39px;">69</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">27.17 </td>
<td style="width: 40px;">103</td>
<td style="width: 46.6px;">40.55 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 54px;">XL</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">104.5</td>
<td style="width: 55px;">41.14 </td>
<td style="width: 39px;">73</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">28.74 </td>
<td style="width: 40px;">107</td>
<td style="width: 46.6px;">42.13</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This CSS & Check Updated HTML

```
 .table-outer{
          overflow: auto;
       }
        .table-outer table{
        min-width:600px;
}
```

```css
.tab-content
    {
        display:none;
    }
    .tab-content.active
    {
        display:block;
    }
    ul.tabs
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding:0;
        margin-left:0;
    }
    li.tab
    {
        display:inline-block;
        padding:10px 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    li.tab.active
    {
        color:grey;
        border-bottom:1px solid red;
    }
    
    .table-outer{
      overflow: auto;
      padding:0 20px;
    }
    .table-outer table{min-width:600px;}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
 
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab" data-content-id="Description">tab 1</li>
        <li class="tab" data-content-id="Size chart">tab 2</li>
        <li class="tab" data-content-id="Reviews">tab 3</li>
    </ul>
 
    <div id="tab-content-1" class="tab-content">content 1</div>
    <div id="tab-content-2" class="tab-content" style="display:block;"><div class="table-outer"><div style='overflow-x:auto'>
<table class="t2">
<thead>
<tr>
<td style="width: 54px;" rowspan="2">Size</td>
<td style="width: 112px;" colspan="2">Length</td>
<td style="width: 96px;" colspan="2">Waist</td>
<td style="width: 86.6px;" colspan="2">Hip</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 57px;">CM</td>
<td style="width: 55px;">INCH</td>
<td style="width: 39px;">CM</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">INCH</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">CM</td>
<td style="width: 46.6px;">INCH</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 54px;">S</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">100</td>
<td style="width: 55px;">39.37 </td>
<td style="width: 39px;">61</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">24.02 </td>
<td style="width: 40px;">95</td>
<td style="width: 46.6px;">37.40 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 54px;">M</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">101.5</td>
<td style="width: 55px;">39.96 </td>
<td style="width: 39px;">65</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">25.59 </td>
<td style="width: 40px;">99</td>
<td style="width: 46.6px;">38.98 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 54px;">L</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">103</td>
<td style="width: 55px;">40.55 </td>
<td style="width: 39px;">69</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">27.17 </td>
<td style="width: 40px;">103</td>
<td style="width: 46.6px;">40.55 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 54px;">XL</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">104.5</td>
<td style="width: 55px;">41.14 </td>
<td style="width: 39px;">73</td>
<td style="width: 57px;">28.74 </td>
<td style="width: 40px;">107</td>
<td style="width: 46.6px;">42.13</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div></div></div>
    <div id="tab-content-3" class="tab-content">content 3</div>
 
    <script>
        tabs= document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
        tabContents= document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content');
 
        tabs.forEach(function(tab){
            tab.addEventListener('click',function(){
 
                contentId = this.dataset.contentId;
                content = document.getElementById(contentId);
 
                tabContents.forEach(function(content){
                    content.classList.remove('active');
                });
 
                tabs.forEach(function(tab){
                    tab.classList.remove('active');
                });
 
                this.classList.add('active');
                content.classList.add('active');
            });
        });
    </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, there is still the same problem. When I tried it with my phone, half of the table was out of the screen and I couldnt scroll horizontally. I also attached the html code that I use for the table if it helps.

Comment: still  it is not working. It works on desktop but not on phone